# How to get list of pages in WCM (Liferay)?

Tags: liferay, freemarker

I tried to create a Web Content with a Template that contains the **navigation** (list of pages):

```
<nav id="navigation">
    <ul>
        <#list nav_items as nav_item>
            <#assign nav_item_css_class = "" />

            <#if nav_item.isSelected()>
                <#assign nav_item_css_class = "selected" />
            </#if>

            <li class="${nav_item_css_class}">
                <a href="${nav_item.getURL()}">${nav_item.getName()}</a>

                <#if nav_item.hasChildren()>
                    <ul class="child-menu">
                        <#list nav_item.getChildren() as nav_child>
                            <#assign nav_child_css_class = "" />
                            <#if nav_item.isSelected()>
                                <#assign nav_child_css_class = "selected" />
                            </#if>
                            <li class="${nav_child_css_class}">
                                <a href="${nav_child.getURL()}">${nav_child.getName()}</a>
                            </li>
                        </#list>
                    </ul>
                </#if>
            </li>
        </#list>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

But I get this error:

```
Expression nav_items is undefined
```

In my theme `navigation.ftl` it works but in the WCM `ftl` (*FreeMarker*) doesn't work.
Then, how can I get the list of pages in WCM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list of pages is available only in [ADTs](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/using-application-display-templates-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-07-en) (Application Display Templates), not in [WCM templates](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/user-guide/-/ai/advanced-content-with-structures-and-te-liferay-portal-6-2-user-guide-03-en).

If you really need the list and can use ADTs, use `navItems` variable instead. The variable `nav_items` only works in themes (for backward compatibility, I guess).

Documentation - hard to find. Use the force, read the source - on [GitHub](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/template/TemplateContextHelper.java#L307).

You may want to use a handy Freemarker script to display all available variables - see [Dumping ADT+WCM Template Variables](https://www.liferay.com/web/james.falkner/blog/-/blogs/dumping-adt-wcm-template-variables) on James Falkner's blog.

Comment: Thank you so much Tomas, but I get the same error: `Expression navItems is undefined`. I am using _Liferay Portal Community Edition 6.2 CE GA4_.

Comment: Just to make the problem more clear - What exactly do you mean by WCM template? Is it a template for a custom structure? Can you please run the dump.ftl script I linked to see the list of all available variables? That means paste dump.ftl code to your template and to check the result.

Comment: Yes, is a FreeMarker Template. You can [see here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1hqYB1d3C1f7nCCHUITiddLbcBUJhR_EvlfF3YYvLjFQ/edit?usp=sharing) all available variables.

Comment: My answer was related to ADTs (Application Display Templates). I would expect the variable set to be the same, but unfortunately it differs. Variable `navItems` is indeed available only for ADT templates. What is your use case? If you really need list of pages inside WCM template, you can always use `serviceLocator` to call `LayoutLocalService` to get the list.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!! It works on ADT. Now I will use an ADT template, but If there is an example on how to get a list of pages inside WCM template, I will try.